# Extracting info from Twitter XML to Wordpress

Tags: php, xml, twitter

I'm wanting to use raw data from Facebook and Twitter on my website. I've worked out extracting data from the Facebook XML (with help from a nice bloke) and I've installed a nice slider thing.  Here is the details of that...

```
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=www.dori.co.nz".urlencode($source_url);

$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$shares =  $xml->link_stat->share_count;
$likes =  $xml->link_stat->like_count;
$comments = $xml->link_stat->comment_count;
$total = $xml->link_stat->total_count;
$max = max($shares,$likes,$comments);
```

Now I want to do the same for Twitter. [Here](http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info?url=http://dori.co.nz/) is the XML page for Twitter, but I can't seem to make it work no matter what I do. Any tips?  Is there an issue with plucking details from two different XML pages/files within the one .php file?

Thank you!!